# Recursively decrement int value using Akka (example)

Tags: java, recursion, akka

There is a bug somewhere in the code below (trying recursion with Akka). Algorithm stops and the process (Java Application) is executed forever in JVM unless I kill it from the System Monitor. I believe it should be a very simple hack to fix it.

[Here is an example](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.1/intro/getting-started-first-java.html) on how to use Akka for parallel Pi approximation. Below is an attempt to show how Akka works with recursive Actors. So the master creates 2 workers, sends them the same message to decrement some `int` value. They do that in parallel and check if the integer value is not equal to 0. If so, they return the result integer value (0) to the master or they both create again 2 workers and send them a recently decremented value.. If the depth of this tree is greater than 1 (the integer was of >1 value) then workers send their results to the workers that called them and only in the end to the master. Well, it is really easy as below (Decrement, NewIntValue and FinalIntValue are essentially the same, they have different names to make it more understandable):

```
import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import akka.actor.ActorSystem;
import akka.actor.Props;
import akka.actor.UntypedActor;
import akka.actor.UntypedActorFactory;
import akka.routing.RoundRobinRouter;

public class StackOverFlow {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StackOverFlow rid = new StackOverFlow();
        rid.start(2);
    }

    public void start(final int workersNumber) {
        // create an Akka system
        ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("IntDec");
        // create the result listener, which will print the result and shutdown the system
        final ActorRef listener = system.actorOf(new Props(Listener.class), "listener");
        // create the master
        ActorRef master = system.actorOf(new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
            public UntypedActor create() {
                return new Master(workersNumber, listener);
            }
        }), "master");
        // start the computation
        master.tell(new Compute());
    }

    static class Compute {}

    static class Decrement {
        private final int intValue;
        public Decrement(int value) {
            this.intValue = value;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return intValue;
        }
    }

    static class NewIntValue {
        private final int intValue;
        public NewIntValue(int value) {
            intValue = value;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return intValue;
        }
    }

    static class FinalIntValue {
        private final int intValue;
        public FinalIntValue(int value) {
            intValue = value;
        }
        public int getValue() {
            return intValue;
        }
    }

    public static class Worker extends UntypedActor {

        private int resultsNumber = 0;
        private final int messagesNumber = 2;

        private final ActorRef workerRouter;

        public Worker(final int workersNumber) {

            workerRouter = getContext().actorOf(
                    new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
                        public UntypedActor create() {
                            return new Worker(workersNumber);
                        }
                    }).withRouter(
                        new RoundRobinRouter(workersNumber)
                    ), "workerRouter");

        }

        public void onReceive(Object message) {

            if (message instanceof Decrement) {
                // get and decrement the int value
                Decrement job = (Decrement) message;
                int intValue = job.getValue();
                System.out.println("\tWorker:Decrement " + intValue);
                intValue--;
                if (intValue == 0) {
                    // we are finished
                    getSender().tell(new NewIntValue(intValue), getSelf());
                    // stop this actor and all its supervised children
                    getContext().stop(getSelf());
                } else {
                    for (int i = 0; i < messagesNumber; i++) {
                        // notify a worker
                        workerRouter.tell(new Decrement(intValue), getSelf());
                    }
                }

            } else if (message instanceof NewIntValue) {

                NewIntValue newInt = (NewIntValue) message;
                int intValue = newInt.getValue();

                System.out.println("\tWorker:NewIntValue!!! " + intValue);

                resultsNumber++;
                if (resultsNumber == messagesNumber) {
                    // we are finished
                    getSender().tell(new NewIntValue(intValue), getSelf());
                    // stop this actor and all its supervised children
                    getContext().stop(getSelf());
                }

            } else unhandled(message);
        }

    }

    public static class Master extends UntypedActor {

        private int resultsNumber = 0;
        private final int messagesNumber = 2;

        private int intValue = 2;

        private final ActorRef listener;
        private final ActorRef workerRouter;

        public Master(final int workersNumber, ActorRef listener) {

            this.listener = listener;

            workerRouter = getContext().actorOf(
                    new Props(new UntypedActorFactory() {
                        public UntypedActor create() {
                            return new Worker(workersNumber);
                        }
                    }).withRouter(
                        new RoundRobinRouter(workersNumber)
                    ), "workerRouter");

        }

        public void onReceive(Object message) {

            if (message instanceof Compute) {

                System.out.println("\tMaster:Compute " + intValue);

                System.out.println(
                        "\n\tInitial integer value: " + intValue);

                for (int i = 0; i < messagesNumber; i++) {
                    workerRouter.tell(new Decrement(intValue), getSelf());
                }

            } else if (message instanceof NewIntValue) {

                NewIntValue newInt = (NewIntValue) message;
                intValue = newInt.getValue();

                System.out.println("\tMaster:NewIntValue " + intValue);

                resultsNumber++;
                if (resultsNumber == messagesNumber) {
                    // send the result to the listener
                    listener.tell(new FinalIntValue(intValue), getSelf());
                    // stop this actor and all its supervised children
                    getContext().stop(getSelf());
                }

            } else unhandled(message);

        }

    }

    public static class Listener extends UntypedActor {

        public void onReceive(Object message) {

            if (message instanceof FinalIntValue) {
                FinalIntValue finalInt = (FinalIntValue) message;
                System.out.println(
                        "\n\tFinal integer value: " + finalInt.getValue());
                getContext().system().shutdown();
            } else {
                unhandled(message);
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I don't know much about akka but I can't believe this is the simplest way to decrement a value using akka.  Try stripping down the code to the bare essentials and your problem should be more obvious.

Comment: Question - where is the problem in the code - it is not working unfortunately. I do need recursion behaviour, I do not need to decrement an integer with Akka, this is just an example of recursion.

Comment: My problem is much more complicated and it computes different things rather than decrementing integers, but reducing the problem to the most simple case, I can find where is the bug in the structure.

Comment: Is this homework by any chance?

Comment: No, this is a simplified version of my problem which can be easily understood - trying to explain that the 3rd time :)

Comment: can you remove unwanted code? It definitely affects `Readability` of question.

Comment: I still don't understand what the actual problem is. Can you explain what you expect and what you get?

Comment: Got back the code that can be compiled. In the `Master` class, if `intValue = 1`, then everything works (Master creates two Workers, sends them 1, they decrement it and send back to Master 0, which it then publishes). The problem occurs if `intValue = 2` - my java application hangs forever in memory and to stop it I only need to kill the corresponding process, in particular `getSender()` method does not work. So first time the Worker receives the Decrement message, I need to save a Sender reference: `Type rightSender = getSender();` Please tell me what to put instead of `Type`? `ActorRef`?

Comment: Or more simply, how to get the Parent reference for a Worker (it can be either Master or Worker), something like `getParent`.. If I can get the Parent, I will be able to send him the result, otherwise I send it to the deeper by recursion Worker, or Child - what makes this problem. So that's why the app hangs on - the first and second Workers are sending messages each other! Great explanation. Now, anybody understands? :)

Comment: Please read the documentation: http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.0.2/#akka.actor.ActorContext

Comment: I did it! Using `getContext().parent()` made the first-level Workers stop at the very end because as I print `getContext().parent().toString()`, it says: `parent = Actor[akka://IntDec/user/master/workerRouter]`, so the parent for them is Master's workerRouter, but not the Master itself. Then I just saved Master reference for that case. Everything is working now, thanks! Reading docs is hard as they contain too little words. There should be some narrative with pictures elsewhere to make the docs human-readable :) Anyway, the show must go on.

Comment: There is narrative and pictures: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/general/addressing.html
 Reading through the documentation is a good way of saving time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add `private ActorRef sender;` to the `Worker` class;
2. add `sender = getSender();` at the beginning of the `Decrement` message;
3. change `getSender()` to `sender` in the `NewIntValue` method of the
   `Worker` class;